# Intermediary Corda Node for incoming and outgoing message

Tags: corda

Can I create a corda node basically I don't want to store any state. Purpose of this nodes is to handle communication between nodes in the same network and outside network.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to do this. The whole idea of a Corda and having corda node's communication is to make sure that all parties have the same view of database, to make sure that "what you see is what I see".

If they aren't going to be any states, it doesn't make sense to put in the efforts to setup a node, you might simply have a simple database or a queue in between instead.